# in python, how do you denote required parameters and optional parameters in code?

Tags: python, function

especially when there are so many parameters (10+ 20+).

What are good ways of enforcing `required/optional` parameters to a function?

What are some good books that deal with this kind of questions for python?
(like effective c++ for c++)

** EDIT **

I think it's very unpractical to list `def foo(self, arg1, arg2, arg3,  .. arg20, .....):` when there are so many required parameters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017996/python-optional-parameter Does this help?

Comment: a good resource for python even if you are not learning to program is http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

Comment: Having a large number of arguments in a function is a good indicator you should refactor your code, probably breaking it into multiple functions.

Comment: Generally speaking for most programming languages, if your function has > 5 parameters your code starts to get bad code smell. > 10 has really really bad code smell and would force me to question the entire project's design and/or the author. But there are always exceptions. (I have worked with code that took 10 or so parameters everyone agreed it was bad... a temporary band aid was to put the parameters into a struct).

Comment: Suppose you are creating an `importer` that imports product data from excel sheet. It goes over +10 easily. How do you suppose to break them?

Answer (score 14):

Parameters can be required or optional depending on how they appear in the function definition:

```
def myfunction(p1, p2, p3=False, p4=5)
```

In this definition, parameters `p1` and `p2` are required.  `p3` is optional and will acquire the value `False` if not provided by the caller.  `p4` is also optional and will acquire the value `5` if not provided.

If you really need to pass ten or more parameters into a function, it might be better to pass them as a dictionary:

```
args = {'a': something, 'b': something_else, 'c': 5, 'd': 99.99, ... }
myfunc(args)
```

Comment: Not sure I agree with the last comment, passing something as a `dict` if there are a number of (variable) args, this would make understanding code much harder and more error prone. I would use `*args` or `**kwargs`, then you can then mix required and optional.

Answer (score 4):

If a function parameter is not required, you can set it equal to None.

```
def hello(first_name, last_name=None):
    print "Hello " + first_name
```

Or as John Gordon said, you can set a parameter with a default value the same way.

Note that optional parameters need to be defined after the required parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You can denote required keyword argument as follows:

```
def myfunc(positional_arg, *, required_kwarg, optional_kwarg=None, **other_kwargs):
  pass
```

Answer (score 2):

**One way is to have your required parameters be named like `func(a, b, c=1)` and this would denote required because the code will error out at runtime if missing any. Then for the optional parameters you would then use Python's `args` and `kwargs`.**

**Of course anytime you use Python's `args` and `kwargs` means additional code to pull the parameter from the `args` and `kwargs`.**

Additionally for each combination of optional parameters you then would need to code a bunch of conditional control flow.

In addition you don't want too many optional assignments because it makes the code's API to complex to describe... and the control flow have to many lines of code because the number of possible combinations grows very quickly for each additional optional parameter.

AND your test code grows EVEN faster...

Comment: Also... the big difference between compiled languages and interpreted when it comes to required vs optional parameters is if you forget a required parameter... you only find that bug at runtime. Ex: a function with parameters x and y, if you forget parameter y then you only get the error at runtime.