# How to make function arguments optional?

Tags: python

For example, I want to be able to inject a behavior if I want to inside a function, but if I don't have a behavior, I want it to have a default behavior

```
class TestDefaultParam:
   def defaultBehavior(file1, file2):
      return 2

   def action(file1, file2, behave=defaultBehavior):
      return behave(file1, file2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   some = TestDefaultParam()
   print(some.action("test", "test"))
```

If this isn't possible how can I change behavior of action at will?

with this code I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ".\test.py", line 10, in <module>
     print(some.action("test", "test"))
    File ".\test.py", line 6, in action
     return behave(file1, file2)
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you already have?

Comment: why tagged as `oop`?

Comment: Show the full traceback and where you called `action`. What did you set `behave=`? A string?

Comment: Your code works fine when we provide reasonable defaults for code you didn't supply.

Comment: You're not accepting `self` as the first argument of your methods, so `behave` is actually the second argument you're passing, i.e. `"test"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017996/is-there-a-way-to-pass-optional-parameters-to-a-function) will help. In your case,

```
def action(file1, file2, behavior=defaultBehavior):
    return behave(file1, file2)
```

is okay. But of course, if an argument is passed into the "behave" parameter, you should take care of it in your function. For instance, if you called

```
action("somefile", "anotherfile", customBehavior)
```

then you'll want something like the following to deal with it:

```
def action(file1, file2, behavior=defaultBehavior):

    if behave != defaultBehavior: # this means that behavior was set to something
        behave(file1, file2, behavior)
    else: # in this case, behave == defaultBehavior
        behave(file1, file2)
```

Something similar can be constructed for `behave()`.